# My app crashes on button click to start activity, but works in emulator

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-button

I have an android app which starts out at the main activity that contains a navigation view, and a fragment called fragment_home which has my start button. When I hit that button, another activity is started. This works fine in the device emulator, but it also works when I plug my phone in and build directly to it **(Pixel 3XL with Android 9)**.

However, if I manually install the APK and run it with my phone unplugged, the main activity opens up fine and displays the home fragment contents, but when I press the button the app immediately crashes. Here is the code for my

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*
        *   Avoid reloading fragment when device is rotated
        */

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.fragment_home);
        }

    }

    /*  Add functionality to the navigation drawer items    */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.history:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HistoryFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.help:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HelpFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void buttonClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.startButton:

                /*  Start the survey activity   */
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SurveyClass.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `buttonClick()` function is the one that is run when the button from my home fragment is clicked.

**Here is my home fragment XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rounded_corners_white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuib"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="FIND PRODUCTS"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/subtitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When there is crash there is stacktrace . Check logs and add the error logs with question .

Comment: can u tel me the error ?

Comment: How do I check for the error when I'm running the app off my physical device while it is unplugged?

Comment: Plug the device in -> Run the app on physical device -> Check the log for errors and update the question

Comment: If I plug in the device and run the app off of it it works. It only crashes when I install it manually and run it when the phone is unplugged

Comment: Are you installing a `debug apk` or a `signed apk` manually?

Comment: A debug APK. I think it's a problem with the version of fragments I am using though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you work with android support v4 Fragment ?
If it's the case you need to use

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

instead of

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder_home, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

Can you also post the error obtained ?

Comment: How do I know which fragments I am using? At first I was using v4, but I changed it all to regular fragments. Also, I can't get the error since the app only crashes when the device is unplugged

Comment: android.app.Fragment is now deprecated (as of API level 28), and everyone should move to using the support library implementations.

Comment: So what do I have to change to do this? Is it something in gradle?

Comment: Your fragment just need to extends v4 Fragment( android.support.v4.app.Fragment ) E.g : MyFragment extends Fragment { ... }

Comment: Do I import android.app.Fragment? Or another library?

Comment: You need to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Just change all of my imports to v4, and changes everything to getSupportFragmentManager(). Still has the same crash when I click the button

Comment: It still crash if you install manually the apk then open app and plug the phone ?

Comment: I found the error. It was in my survey class where getWindowManager() was being called on a null context. A simple if statement has fixed it. I have no idea why this crash doesn't occur when building directly to the device, but everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

This might be android 9 error!
Add this line in your Manifest file within application

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```